# Explicit chaining with lodash doesn't apply shortcut fusion

Tags: javascript, node.js, lodash

While working with lodash, I found that it applied shortcut fusion when I used implicit chaining.

```
$ node -e 'const _ = require("lodash"); _([1,2,3]).map(n => { console.log(n); return n }).find(n => n <= 1)'
1
```

But when I changed this snippet to use explicit chaining, it doesn't apply shortcut fusion.

```
$ node -e 'const _ = require("lodash"); _.chain([1,2,3]).map(n => { console.log(n); return n }).find(n => n <= 1).value()'
1
2
3
```

As you can see, a function passed to `map` was called three times instead of once, which indicates lodash didn't apply shortcut fusion.

From their document, shortcut fusion should seem to be applied in both cases.

1. Is this an intended behavior?
2. Where in the document do they explain this behavior if so?
3. Is there any ways to apply shortcut fusion with explicit chaining?

I use lodash 4.17.5 on node.js v8.10.0.

Comment: what is the problem with the code?

Comment: Added versions of node and lodash.

Comment: @NinaScholz As I wrote in the question, lodash doesn't apply shortcut fusion when I use explicit chaining.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [a ticket](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/issues/3601) about this issue at their GitHub project.

> It's unexpected but is what it is for now.